# VueJS globally usage of css modules

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, css-modules

I was wondering if I can use css modules by just writing css in classes and do nothing more.
by simply writing `<div class="text-xs text-black bg-blue-500">` can it be transformed to `[sha1:hash:hex:6]` ? Here let me explain.

I made a tiny utility class that import my main css file and calls the style.

```js
import tailwind from "@/Assets/main.css";

export const style = (classList) => {
    return classList.split(' ').map(_class => {
        return tailwind[_class]
    })
}
```

I assign this utility script to Vue.prototype so I can use it like this:

```js
<div :class="$style('text-xs text-black bg-blue-500')">
```

However this kills my readability of code and if was using `class` and `:class` at the same time so converting my code to double `:class` gives error of "duplicate class attribute". So I am researching how Vue render what's inside  and can I manipulate the elements inside  while Vue creating the component so I can replace the classes with my utility script but it's a dead end.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: I thought you could just import the css in your main.js and call the class normally with <div class="text-xs text-black bg-blue-500"> or did I missunderstood your question ?

Comment: when you enable css-loader's modules feature, styles are transformed into js objects like {key: 'bg-blue-500'} so you can use style.key in a class or something in your vdom. The question is I wanna use it in vue template just like normal classes usage but while vue transforming it I wanna split the classes and apply the transformation

Comment: @T.CemYılmaz I am also trying to achieve this, have you succeed in implementing this

Comment: Sorry, I am still using $style kind of thing. Wrote my own function which finds and returns styles from tailwind